# PC800, one thump/knock on opening throttle

Tags: honda, shadow

When opening the throttle, doesn't seem to matter which speed or RPM, there is a noticeable thump/knock. For this to happen the bike has to be in gear. It doesn't happen when you roll on the throttle really slow. After replacing the drive shaft oil the thump/knock became even harder.

Can someone tell me what is producing this sound?

Comment: Put the bike on a stand with engine in gear and rock the rear wheel. Is there play or any clunks? Check all of your engine mounts to make sure engine is secure.